# Possible to get the full url behind javascript button?

Tags: javascript, websites

I am programming a little tool for patching. I found the microsoft update catalog, where all updates are stored, and I managed to look for some of them.

But my problem is now that the actual download link is behind a button, which opens a new window where I can't see the actual URL with the GET parameter.

I already tried to intercept GET/POST requests through chrome but it didn't trigger the dev tools of chrome, since it opens a new window.

The button I am talking about is for example here: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=MS16-141

Can anybody help me out on this one and give me a link with the parameter which https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/DownloadDialog.aspx uses?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the whole listing of updates, first you should write an xpath to get the uids of each download button, you should get a bunch of uids like `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

After that, POST to `https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/DownloadDialog.aspx` with `[{"size":0,"languages":"","uidInfo":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","updateID":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}]` should give you all the data you need.

To obtain this data, just open a chrome window of one of the download buttons and open dev-tools on it, then just inspect the network traffic and check the request headers, that should be enough.